# probability density function question

Tags: probability, statistics

The diameter of grains of sand from a sand pit, measured in mm, can be considered a continuous random variable X with probability density (picewise function)

f(x)=4(x-x^3), 0<=x<=1, otherwise f(x)=0

a) find P(X<=1/4)

b)Find E[X+2] and Var[2X]

anyone know how to go about these two questions? on a) do I just integrate 4(x-x^3) over 0 to 1/4 ? on b im pretty much clueless..

any tips/solutions? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a), you are right.

For b), there are two options. One is to find
$$\int_0^1 (x+2)[4(x-x^3)]\,dx.$$
Another is to note that $E(X+2)=E(X)+E(2)=E(X)+2$. To compute $E(X)$, use $\int_0^1 (x)[4(x-x^3)]\,dx$.

For the variance of $2X$ you could proceed directly. However, I prefer to use $\text{Var}(kX)=k^2\text{Var}(X)$. So we want $4\text{Var}(X)$.

To find $\text{Var}(X)$, use the fact that it is equal to $E(X^2)-(E(X))^2$. And then use $E(X^2)=\int_0^1 (x^2)[4(x-x^3)]\,dx$.

Comment: hmm.. I found E(X)= 8/15 so E(X+2) is 38/15 then? since you said E(X+2)=E(X)+2 :D?

Comment: Yes, you have these two right.

Comment: ahh ok nice, hmm I got E(X^2) = 1/3 and (E(X)^2 = 64/225 so Var(X)=11/225 and var(2X)= 4var(X)= 44/225? :D

Comment: Yes, that calculation is also right.

Comment: nice man! thanks a lot for the help! you're a legend

Comment: You are welcome. After the basics are under control, it comes down to calculation, which you can probably do as well or better than I can.

Answer (score 0):

For (a) your suggestion will work.

For (b) $\displaystyle E[X+2] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (X+2) f(x) dx$, though the definition of $f(x)$ here in effect reduces the range of integration to $[0,1]$

$Var[2X]=E[(2X)^2]-(E[2X])^2$ which you can calculate in a similar way.